# Angular 5 bind model with localstorage

Tags: angular

Is there a way to bind a local variable (model) in a component with a localstorage item.

For e.g. when an item `user` is removed from `localStorage`, my component's model variable automatically gets empty and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a user service and observables to keep all components updated

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

  usersChanged = new Subject<string[]>();

  users: string[] = [];

  constructor() { }


  addUser(user: string) {
    this.users.push(user);
    this.usersChanged.next(this.users);
  }
  remove(index: number) {
    this.users.splice(index, 1);
    this.usersChanged.next(this.users);
  }

  getUsers() {
    return this.users.slice();
  }
}
```

Then in your every dependent component you can subscribe to any changes

```
  users: string[] = this.storageService.getUsers();

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storageService.usersChanged
      .subscribe( (users ) => this.users = users);
  }
```

Comment: works with some changes, actually needed for just a single user, not many users, but it gives an idea, thanks

Comment: @M.ImranMamda, fixed (just forgot to define array on declaration in service)